# Why isn't $ \alpha_p $ smooth?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

In caracteristic $p$, there is a finite subgroup $ \alpha_p \subset \mathbb{G}_a $ where we define the functor of points of $ \alpha_p $ by associating to a $ k $ - algebra $ R $ :
$$ \alpha_p (R) = \{ \ c \in \mathbb{G}_a (R) \ | \ c^p = 0 \ \} $$
This is represented by the scheme $ \mathrm{Spec} k[t] / (t^p ) $ and so $ \alpha_p $ is unipotent group.

Could you explain to me please, in details, ans step by step, how do we reason to show that $ \alpha_p $ is not smooth ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What is $\;\Bbb G_a\;$ , anyway?

Comment: @DonAntonio The additive group : $\mathbb{A}^1$ with the addition.

Comment: I think, since $ \alpha_p $ is an affine scheme of finite type over $ k $ so it's has a closed immersion into the affine underlying space of $ \mathbb{G}_a $ which is $ \mathbb{A}^1 $, no ? so, $ \alpha_p $ is the closed subscheme defined by $ f(c) = c^p = 0 $. To show that, $ \{ f=0 \} $ is not smooth means to show that $ \exists x \in \{ f = 0 \} $ such that the derivatives $ \displaystyle \Big( \dfrac{ \partial f }{ \partial c }(x) \displaystyle \Big) $ has rank $ < 1 - \mathrm{dim} \alpha_p $, no ?

Comment: I don't know your definition of smoothness, but you can see that $\alpha_p$ is not reduced, so it can't be smooth over $k$. Also, you can compute the differential of $t^p$ which is zero, so it is not surjective.

Comment: @YoYo Yes what you wrote is correct.

Comment: @Roland : Yes, that is true what you wrote, thank you very much. $ \alpha_p $ is not reduced because it's has nilpotent in $ \sqrt{ \alpha_p (R)} $ , right ?

Comment: It is not reduced because $t$ is nilpotent ($t^p=0$ in $\alpha_p$). I don't know what you mean by $\sqrt{\alpha_p(R)}$.

Comment: Thank you very much Roland.  :)

Comment: Sorry, i mean : $ \sqrt{ (t^p) } = \{ c \ | \ \exists \alpha \in \mathbb{N} \backslash \{0\} \ : \ c^\alpha = e \ \} $. It's called the radical of $ (t^p) $ which is the intersection of all the prime ideals containing the ideal $ (t^p) $, right ?

Comment: Just a remark, in english we say "characteristic" and not "caracterstic" :-)

Comment: The way the answers to this question are written is possibly confusing. 
Here's a possible correction. Reducedness is a smooth local (even flat local) condition. Therefore if $X\to Y$ is a morphism of schemes then $X$ is reduced iff $Y$ is. In this situation clearly $Y$ is reduced and $X$ isn't. Therefore the structure morphism cannot be smooth.